# had to login twice for plone

Tags: nginx, plone

I have set a plone product server with nginx + varnish + haproxy + 4 instance.(the buildout  deploy configuration is come from the professional plone4 development book writted by Martin).
Now I have troubles with login process. I had to submit login info two times for signing in plone site.

I don't kown if nginx needs some settings like apache with mod_auth_ktk,or plone.session must adjust some parameters.

In fact , If I directly access instance using http://demo.com:8001/Plone address , it is OK.

Thanks.

Comment: Please indicate which version of Plone you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially several causes of this problem, but the most common is a misconfiguration of the virtual hosting setup that causes some page resources to be served from a different URL than others.

View source on the browser, and look for differences in the URL between the page itself and the CSS/JS resources. If you find any, work on your virtual-hosting specifications.